# Netezza:ERROR [HY000] ERROR: pg_atoi: error in "[NULL]": can't parse "[NULL]"

Tags: sql, toad, netezza

I have loaded my files to Netezza from db2 using NZload.  To use the NZload first we need to create a table in Netezza to receive the data, so I created table `Table1` for that purpose, with all columns having datatype `character varying`.  I successfully loaded all the records into this table.

Now I want to change the datatype of few columns to `date` to enable me to search by month and year criteria.  I have created another table, `Table2`, with columns having datatype `date`, and while trying to move data from `Table1` into `Table2` I get an error:

```
"ERROR [HY000] ERROR: pg_atoi: error in "[NULL]": can't parse "[NULL]" "
```

What must I do to successfully perform this datatype conversion?

The DDL for the two tables:

```
CREATE TABLE ID1
   (
      ID          CHARACTER VARYING(100) NULL,
      ID_NUM      CHARACTER VARYING(100) NULL,
      CREATE_TIME CHARACTER VARYING(100) NULL,
      CRT_DTE     CHARACTER VARYING(100) NULL,
      UPDATE_TIME CHARACTER VARYING(100) NULL,
      PLAN_YEAR   CHARACTER VARYING(100) NULL,
      DLV_DTE     CHARACTER VARYING(100) NULL,
      STATUS      CHARACTER VARYING(100) NULL
   );

CREATE TABLE ID2
   (
      ID          INTEGER NULL,
      ID_NUM      INTEGER NULL,
      CREATE_TIME DATETIME NULL,
      CRT_DTE     DATETIME NULL,
      UPDATE_TIME DATETIME NULL,
      PLAN_YEAR   INTEGER NULL,
      DLV_DTE     DATETIME NULL,
      STATUS      CHARACTER VARYING(100) NULL
   );
```

Comment: Can you provide the ddl for the two tables? This sort of error usually means you have data in a source column that can't be implicitly cast to the target column

Comment: And also provide a sample of how the dates are represented in your ingest varchar columns.

Comment: Scott, create table ID1
(
ID           character varying(100) null,  
ID_NUM    character varying(100) null,
CREATE_TIME        character varying(100) null, 
CRT_DTE  character varying(100) null,
UPDATE_TIME character varying(100) null,
PLAN_YEAR character varying(100) null, 
DLV_DTE character varying(100) null, 
STATUS                character varying(100) null    )

Comment: Table2: create table ID2
(
ID           integer null,  
ID_NUM    integer null,
CREATE_TIME        datetime null, 
CRT_DTE   datetime null,
UPDATE_TIME datetime null,
PLAN_YEAR integer null, 
 DLV_DTE datetime null, 
STATUS                character varying(100) null    );

Comment: --Load data 
insert into  ID2 
select * from ID1-- Error ("ERROR [HY000] ERROR: pg_atoi: error in "[NULL]": can't parse "[NULL]" ")-- 
I have altered the table ID1:alter table ID1 alter column update_time datetime; It results in an error
(error ^ found "DATETIME" (at char 73) expecting `DROP' or `SET')

Comment: I got this error message because of a line in the `WHERE` clause, that checked a varchar column for `column <> -1`. (-1 was an occasional string value, to be excluded.)  Putting single quotes around the `-1` got rid of the error:  `column <> '-1'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Netezza will implicitly convert character columns to other data types when it can figure out how the character data can be properly converted.

For example:

```
TESTDB.ADMIN(ADMIN)=> insert into id1 values
TESTDB.ADMIN(ADMIN)-> (NULL, NULL , '1999-1-1', '2010-01-31', '2014-12-1', NULL, '1900-01-1', NULL);
INSERT 0 1
TESTDB.ADMIN(ADMIN)=> insert into id2 select * from id1;
INSERT 0 1
TESTDB.ADMIN(ADMIN)=> select * from id2;
 ID | ID_NUM |     CREATE_TIME     |       CRT_DTE       |     UPDATE_TIME     | PLAN_YEAR |       DLV_DTE       | STATUS
----+--------+---------------------+---------------------+---------------------+-----------+---------------------+--------
    |        | 1999-01-01 00:00:00 | 2010-01-31 00:00:00 | 2014-12-01 00:00:00 |           | 1900-01-01 00:00:00 |
(1 row)
```

However, based on your DDL and output, I believe it's a conversion to INTEGER that is failing.  It seems that somewhere in your data in table ID1 there is a column that contains the text value 'NULL'.

```
TESTDB.ADMIN(ADMIN)=> insert into id1 values 
(NULL, 'NULL', NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL);
INSERT 0 1
TESTDB.ADMIN(ADMIN)=> insert into id2 select * from id1;
ERROR:  pg_atoi: error in "NULL": can't parse "NULL"
TESTDB.ADMIN(ADMIN)=>
```

I'd recommend checking the columns in ID1 to look for the string 'NULL' and perhaps replace with an actual NULL as appropriate.

Once this is resolved, you may find that your date representation in your varchar columns isn't implicitly converted due to an unusual format.  If that's the case, then you may need to use an explicit conversion with the to_date function.

Comment: Scott: 
I checked with Null
select * from ID1
where status id '%null%' or where id = null
for all the columns, and no rows with null have been displayed.
Is there any way, where i can change the datatype of id as integer and datatype of Update_time from character
varying to datetime. if we do this there is no need of loading again into another table2 ie ID2

Comment: You can't alter the type of a column in one step. You'd have to add a new column, update it to be set to the old column, drop the old column, and then rename the new column to the old column's name. The easiest thing to do would be to create a new table with the altered DDL, and select insert into that, then rename the tables.

Comment: Try this for each column in succession to figure out where the "bad" data is:  select ID::INTEGER from ID1;  select ID_NUM::INTEGER from ID1; select CREATE_TIME::TIMESTAMP from ID1;  etc.  And let's see which column it errors on.  Edit: timestamp and datetime are synonyms.

Comment: There are 2.5million records and it is not possible to check the bad data

Comment: The starting point is to know which column is giving us grief, though.  So the work there is independent of the number of rows. You won't be able to get the data into a timestamp format if we don't know which columns are the issue. My hunch is still that it's one of the integer columns.  If you do run "select count(ID::INTEGER) from ID1; select count(ID_NUM::INTEGER) from ID1; select count(PLAN_YEAR::INTEGER) from ID1;" let me know the results.

Comment: It gave the same no of rows for ID and ID_NUM;      select plan_year::integer from CHECK_PLAN_ID1;
select count(PLAN_YEAR::INTEGER) from CHECK_PLAN_ID1; Error:pg_atoi: error in "[NULL]": can't parse "[NULL]" "

Comment: Ok - if you got that error in response to the query against plan_year, run this to check the values that : select plan_year from id1 where plan_year is not null order by plan_year desc limit 5;

Comment: it is displaying the null values in the column Plan_year

Comment: OK, since we specified "where PLAN_YEAR IS NOT NULL" in our query, we know that what you are seeing is not a real NULL, it is actually text (assuming you saw the word NULL) or an empty string (assuming you saw nothing). You will have to clean those up with an update statement before your conversion will work.  We've probably stretched the limits of what we should be doing in comments, so if you need any more assistance I think we should move it to chat.

Comment: I am unable to move to chat.., it is showing not enough reputation..I have loaded into id2, i changed the play_year to character varying; select id, DLV_DTE, STATUS from ID2 where month(DLV_DTE)= 10 and year (DLV_DTE)= 2013

ERROR: Function 'MONTH(TIMESTAMP)' does not exist Unable to identify a function that satisfies the given argument types:

Comment: You can use extract or date_part to do the comparison you are looking for.  Try select id, DLV_DTE, STATUS from ID2 where extract(month from DLV_DTE)= 10 and extract(year from DLV_DTE)= 2013 ;

Comment: Thank you Scott, That worked!! When i am loading a table from txt file to Netezza using NZLOAD, i have created a table with all the columns as "character varying" in Netezza and then loaded,  if i used the datatype "Datetime" for date column it throwed me an error:[1, TIMESTAMP] expected date delimiter, "2"[/].

Comment: Take a look at the -datestyle and -datedlim options for nzload. The default delimiter is '-' but you appear to be using '/', which can be changed with -datedelim.

Comment: i have used pipe delimiter '|' to load the file, i cannot use delim'-'or'/'bcz in my data these delimiters are present

Comment: datedelim is independent of the value you use for a general delimiter. It simply specifies for date/timestamps *only* what the separator is in parts of dates. It has no effect outside of this.

Comment: Scott, I didnot get you exactly.., i tried to load with delimiter'-' and it is not even displaying Nzbad, log file. after that  i tried again with pipe delimiter, and again displayed the same error. My question is can we load a table with NZload using the same datatypes as previous table(bcz we need to convert this to text or csv) and then NZload keeping the old datatypes from different database.

Comment: Keep the value you use for -delim the same, but specify -datedelim '/' as another nzload option.  This specified what character will be found between the day and month and year portions of a date.  For example in 10/01/2014 the datedelim is '/'.  In 10-01-2014 it is '-'. The '-' is the default, but your data is using '/'according to your error:[1, TIMESTAMP] expected date delimiter, "2"[/]. Also there is a -datestyle option that specifies id the date format is Month, Day, Year or Year, Month, Day etc. Please see the documentation here: http://tinyurl.com/jwvtdcz

Comment: where should i specify -datedelim '/' or while creating a new table is it in Nzload syntax? i converted the file in delim'/' and by using in syntax delim '/'. It gave me an error [1, TIMESTAMP] expected date delimiter, "12"[ ]

Comment: It is an option for nzload that you specify in addition to -delim '|'

Answer (score 0):

I have loaded into id2, i changed the play_year to character varying; select id, DLV_DTE, STATUS  from ID2 
where month(DLV_DTE)= 10 and year (DLV_DTE)= 2013

ERROR:  Function 'MONTH(TIMESTAMP)' does not exist
    Unable to identify a function that satisfies the given argument types: